# ASP.net AjaxToolKit LineChart Drawing Series

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following SqlServer Data Table :
Years | Sales(A) | Sales(B)
 
------------------------------
2000  |  38000   |  55000
2001  |  18000   |  47000
2002  |  70000   |  16000
2003  |  21000   |  55000
2004  |  77000   |  50000
2005  |  16000   |  64000
2006  |  82000   |  61000
2007  |  37000   |  16000

and I need to compare these to columns by using AjaxToolKit LineChart
in ASP Page I have the following :

**

> ASPX

**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px">
        <h1>Ajax Database Multiline Chart Tutorial </h1>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Generate Chart" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px">
        <ajaxToolkit:LineChart ID="LineChart1" runat="server" ChartType="Stacked" ChartWidth="720" Width="800px" ChartTitle="Arabian Food Supplies Annual Sales">
        </ajaxToolkit:LineChart>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**

> VB Code

**

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class AjaxLineChartDatabase
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    End Sub


    Protected Sub Compare(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData("SELECT Years,A FROM LineChart")

        Dim x As String() = New String(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim y As Decimal() = New Decimal(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
            y(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(1))
        Next

        LineChart1.Series.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries() With {
         .Name = "Series 1",
         .Data = y
        })



        dt = GetData("SELECT Years,B FROM LineChart")
        y = New Decimal(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
            y(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(1))
        Next
        LineChart1.Series.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries() With {
         .Name = "Series 2",
         .Data = y
        })

        LineChart1.CategoriesAxis = String.Join(",", x)
        LineChart1.ChartTitle = String.Format("{0} and {1} Distribution", "S-1", "S-2")
        LineChart1.Visible = True
    End Sub



    Private Shared Function GetData(query As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ChartsConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                End Using
            End Using
            Return dt
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

The problem when I draw the chart, the first series(A) appears OK but the 2nd Series(B) values appear as A+B

Sample :
[image]
Why I get it like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved the issue** :  it's coming from **ChartType** Property.

Problem:

```
   <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px">
    <ajaxToolkit:LineChart ID="LineChart1" runat="server" ChartType="Stacked" ChartWidth="720" Width="800px" ChartTitle="Sales">
    </ajaxToolkit:LineChart>
```

Solution :

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 500px">
    <ajaxToolkit:LineChart ID="LineChart1" runat="server" ChartType="Basic" ChartWidth="720" Width="800px" ChartTitle="Sales">
    </ajaxToolkit:LineChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

My theory, is the array is just getting appended.  *Note, we may need separate arrays as it's getting rendered after the code.

Try this,

```
        dt = GetData("SELECT Years,A, B FROM LineChart")
        y = New Decimal(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        y2 = New Decimal(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
            y(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(1))
            y2(i) = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(2))
        Next
        LineChart1.Series.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries() With {
         .Name = "Series 2",
         .Data = y
        })
        LineChart1.Series.Add(New AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries() With {
         .Name = "Series 2",
         .Data = y2
        })
        LineChart1.CategoriesAxis = String.Join(",", x)
        LineChart1.ChartTitle = String.Format("{0} and {1} Distribution", "S-1", "S-2")
        LineChart1.Visible = True
```

Comment: I got the 2nd series Ok , but the first series values was turned to zeros.

Comment: Oh I think I know what this is,  It's still pointing to the same data.  We could use a multi-dimensional array or just as easy, go with an x2 and y2 here.  I will change my answer.

Comment: still, I have the same problem.

Comment: I needed to look closer.  X does not change, so if you have "Select years, A, B from LineChart" we could do it in 1 pass to the table.  Another edit in progress.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jimmy... I also tried this way but not succeed.  Also I tried the sample which posted in this URL: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-Line-Chart-Control-Multiple-Series-Populate-from-Database-example.aspx     and not succeed.... really I need help.